# Create JSON array and JSON Object in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I want do this JSON in Swift. But i cant do this....

```
{
    "room": "Platinum",
    "products": [{
        "name": "Agua",
         "quantity": 2
},
{   
    "name":"Cafe",
    "quantity": 4
}],
    "observation": "",
    "date": "2016-08-15 12:00:00"
}
```

My swift code returns this:

```
{
    date = "2016-08-25 18:16:28 +0000";
    observation = "";
    products =     (
            {
                name = cafe;
                quantity = 1;
            }
    );
    room = Platinium;
```

This is my code:

```
let para:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
let prod: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

para.setValue(String(receivedString), forKey: "room")
para.setValue(observationString, forKey: "observation")
para.setValue(stringDate, forKey: "date")

for product in products{
    prod.setValue(product.name, forKey: "name")
    prod.setValue(product.quantity, forKey: "quantity")
    para.setObject([prod], forKey: "products")
}
```

This is my input:

```
{
    name = coffe;
    quantity = 2;
}
{
    name = cappuccino;
    quantity = 1;
}
```

This is output

```
{
    date = "2016-08-25 18:52:30 +0000";
    observation = "";
    products =     (
            {
                name = cappuccino;
                quantity = 1;
            }
    );
    room = Platinium;
}
```

I created a request to send the two products, but the code prints only the last product.

Comment: Little confusing, what is your input (data you work with) a what is the output you mention? Consider to mark input/output staff in your question, please

Comment: You're overwriting the keys in the same dictionary - `prod`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a new `prodArray` array which holds all the `prod` dictionary(name and quantity.) Set this prodArray for `para` array corresponding to `products` key.

Issue in your code:- In your forin loop, you are over-riding the value corresponding to `"products"` key.

```
let para:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
let prodArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

para.setValue(String(receivedString), forKey: "room")
para.setValue(observationString, forKey: "observation")
para.setValue(stringDate, forKey: "date")

for product in products
{
    let prod: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    prod.setValue(product.name, forKey: "name")
    prod.setValue(product.quantity, forKey: "quantity")
    prodArray.addObject(prod)
}

para.setObject(prodArray, forKey: "products")
```

Comment: Hi, I am using your code. However; when I send in the server all the prod values are showng as single entities, not group like we are assigning.

Comment: All the values are assigned to a dictionary. This dictionary is holding an array of the dictionaries. Is it clear now?

Comment: Is there a way I can store multiple key in one dictionary  ? Like for ex: have { name: 'some name' , quanity: '2'} , { ...

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck in similar type of problem. This works like charm

Answer (score 3):

You need to move `let prod: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()` inside the for loop and move `para.setObject([prod], forKey: "products")` after the for loop, but you also need to change so you create and add each `prod` to an array in the loop and then add that array to `para` after the loop.

Your current code keeps replacing things rather than adding so at the end you only have the last one.